# Html removes whitespace at start of line

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, string

I have a string that is being split by lines.

```
testString = "This is line 1\nThis is line 2\n -Description\n -Description2"
```

How to implement without cutting whitespace at start of line?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, the split method does not remove any whitespaces. No matter whether you use `testString.split("\n")` or `testString.splitlines()`, the whitespaces persist. What do you use that removes them?

Comment: Ah yes. You are right. I use Django to display the strings in html template. The problem is html.

Comment: I found the solution `p { white-space:pre;}` needs to be implemented if whitespace should not be cut. Thanks for pointing out that splitlines function is not the problem!

Answer (score 1):

As Martin in comment section of the Question pointed out, the problem is not the python function `splitlines`. I had a problem using that string in html without cutting the whitespaces.

`<p style=" white-space:pre;"<...</p>`  needs to be implemented if whitespace should not be cut in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `.splitlines`:

```
testString = "This is line 1\nThis is line 2\n -Description\n -Description2"
splitted = testString.splitlines()
print(splitted)
```

Output:

```
['This is line 1', 'This is line 2', ' -Description', ' -Description2']
```